# Swagger annotations with linked property array

Tags: annotations, swagger-ui, swagger-php, laravel-5.6

I'm new to PHP Swagger and using the Laravel package [L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) to create documentation for my API. Now I'm trying to let one model contain an array of the other model, an Order can have several OrderItems.

Unfortuantly I cannot get the linking to work. See attached screen shot.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

This is my Order model:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *   required={"order_id","order_items"},
 *   type="object",
 *   @SWG\Xml(name="Order")
 * )
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @SWG\Property(example="O-789456123")
     * @var string
     */
    public $order_id;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="array", items="$ref:OrderItem")
     * @var array
     */
    public $order_items = [];
}
```

This is my OrderItem model:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *   required={"sku","quantity", "price_including_tax"},
 *   type="object",
 *   @SWG\Xml(name="OrderItem")
 * )
 */
class OrderItem
{
    /**
     * @SWG\Property(example="SKU-123")
     * @var string
     */
    public $sku;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(example=2)
     * @var integer
     */
    public $quantity;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(example=199.75)
     * @var float
     */
    public $price_including_tax;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `items="$ref:OrderItem"` should be `@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/OrderItem")`

Ps. Checking the intermediate format (the swagger.json) can provide insight into what going wrong.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!